# Spring security UI grails plugin user register error

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security

I'm using [Spring security grails plugin v4.0.0.M1](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-ui) in my `Grails 3.3.11` application, while testing the **registration and the reset password** actions, in the `register` view I entered a valid `password` but I always get this error `Password must have min 0 and maximum 0 characters` this error occurs in both `register` and `forgetPassword` views in case I entered valid or invalid password, first it is not accepting a valid password , second, the error message arguments are wrong, Is this a bug or I missed something?

Comment: The docs state, that version 3.X of the plugin is for Grails 3.  Have you tried the appropriate version for your Grails version?

Comment: @cfrick I tried ` plugin v3.1.2` still getting the same results

Comment: Any advice or recommendations?